# Infinite Integral involving a Bessel function

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I have trouble evaluating the following numerical integral,

$$
 \int_{0}^{\infty} d k^{(yz)} \, k^{(yz)}  J_{0} \left(d^{(yz)} k^{(yz)} \right) \frac{e^{-i d_x \sqrt{k_R^2 + {k^{(yz)}}^{2} }}}{ \sqrt{k_R^2 + {k^{(yz)}}^{2} }} \\ \times \left(\sqrt{k_R^2 + {k^{(yz)}}^{2} } - k_R \tilde{v} \right)^{q} \left( \tilde{v}\sqrt{k_R^2 + {k^{(yz)}}^{2} } - k_R  \right)^{p} \, .
$$
Here, p and q are positive integers, and $k_R$ and $\tilde{v}$ are positive real numbers. The naive ansatz

```
dyz=10*10^(-9);vt=0.0001;kR= 1.41705*10^9;
NIntegrate[ 
     BesselJ[0, dyz * kyz] * kyz *
  (1/Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2])
  E^(-I Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2]) (-kR*vt + 
     Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2])^
   p (-kR + vt Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2])^
   q, {kyz, 0, Infinity}]
```

gives the warning "NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9
recursive bisections..."

I would be happy if one of you can help me.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained example, including exemplary values for the undefined constants. You will receive much better answers if your code actually runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a stand-alone response, just a follow-up to the response by @user64494 that already settles the issue. We'll do an exact integration here.

```
ee = BesselJ[0, dyz*kyz]*kyz/Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2]*
    E^(-I*Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2])* (-kR*vt + Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2])^
     p *(-kR + vt*Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2])^q /. {dyz -> 10^(-8), 
    vt -> 1/10000, kR -> 141705*10^4};
```

Let's assume `p + q > 1`. then `Integrate` correctly finds that this diverges.

```
Integrate[ee, {kyz, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {p > 0, q > 0, p + q > 1}]

(* During evaluation of In[116]:= Integrate::idiv: Integral of (E^(-I Sqrt[2008030702500000000+kyz^2]) kyz (-1417050000+Sqrt[<<1>>]/10000)^q (-141705+Sqrt[2008030702500000000+kyz^2])^p BesselJ[0,kyz/100000000])/(Sqrt[2008030702500000000+kyz^2]) does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}.

Out[116]= Integrate[(E^(-I Sqrt[2008030702500000000 + kyz^2])
     kyz (-1417050000 + Sqrt[2008030702500000000 + kyz^2]/10000)^
    q (-141705 + Sqrt[2008030702500000000 + kyz^2])^
    p BesselJ[0, kyz/100000000])/(Sqrt[
   2008030702500000000 + kyz^2]), {kyz, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> {p > 0, q > 0, p + q > 1}] *)
```

Comment: This proves the divergence only for concrete values of `dyz`, 
   `vt`, `kR`, but not for the general case `{kR, vt, dyz} > 0`.  The above answer  is only wishful thinking.

Comment: The true answer is obtained in version 13 on Windows 10 by `Integrate[ee, {kyz, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {p > 0, q > 0, p + q > 1, kR > 0, vt > 0, dyz > 0}]`. BTW, I made [the screen of the answer by Daniel](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2lqy8kqfscsainj/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202022-06-20%2021.14.53.png?dl=0).

Comment: DanielLichblau (@ does not work.) :Up to standard textbooks on calculus, the condition `{p>0, q>0, p+q>1/2}` is enough for the divergence.

Comment: No, but it showed the difference between `Integrate` and `NIntegrate`. For the general case: `In[2]:= Integrate[ee, {kyz, 0, Infinity},                                       
 Assumptions -> {p > 0, q > 0, p + q > 1}]                                      
Integrate::idiv: 
   Integral of ... does not converge on {0, Infinity}...` (edited for readibility and length).

Comment: DanielLichblau (@ does not work.) Sorry, don't understand your latest comment where you repeat my comment concerning the true answer. Did you already look in textbooks on calculus?

Comment: What I intended to show in the comment is that `Integrate` can correctly detect the divergence in the general case. As for the mathematical reason, I think we agree it follows from the series expansion.

Comment: By the way, what was the screen shot for?

Comment: I'd like to add that in my comments `ee` stands for `BesselJ[0, dyz*kyz]*kyz/Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2]*
    E^(-I*Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2])* (-kR*vt + Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2])^
     p *(-kR + vt*Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2])^q`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Integrate[ee, {kyz, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {p > 0, q > 0, p + q > 1, kR > 0, vt > 0, dyz > 0}]` returns the input, being executed on a fresh kernel.

Comment: Yes, so I see. Apparently I was checking in a development kernel. So this might be something that got improved for a future release.

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken, the result of

```
Normal[Series[BesselJ[0, dyz*kyz]*kyz*(1/Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2])
E^(-I Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2]) (-kR*vt + Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2])^
p (-kR + vt Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2])^q, {kyz, Infinity, 1}, 
Assumptions -> {p, q} \[Element]  PositiveIntegers && {kR, vt, dyz, kyz} > 0]] // Simplify
```

> `(1/(dyz^(5/2) Sqrt[\[Pi]]))(1/16 + I/16) E^(-((I (kR^2 + 2 kyz^2))/( 2 kyz))) kyz^(-(3/2) + p +  q) vt^q (dyz (I + 8 dyz kyz) (Cos[dyz kyz] -  I Sin[dyz kyz]) + (-I + 8 dyz kyz) Abs[ dyz] (-I Cos[dyz kyz] + Sin[dyz kyz]))`

implies the divergence at infinity (pay your attention to `kyz^(-(3/2) + p + q)`).

Comment: Yes right, for several p and q, the integrand diverges for kyz->infinity. But the integrand is heavily oscillatory leading to a finite integral? I am not sure about that statement, but NIntegrate gives finite results for the integral apart from the large error of course.

Comment: @Chopin: Your words "But the integrand is heavily oscillatory..." do not correspond to reality because `E^(-((I (kR^2 + 2 kyz^2))/( 2 kyz))) ` oscillates at infinity as `Sin[2*kyz]` and `Cos[2*kyz]` as well as the multiplier `(-I Cos[dyz kyz] + Sin[dyz kyz]))`.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on that. So you are essentially saying that the integral should diverge because of kyz^(-(3/2) + p +  q) being divergent, right? I mean from that I would also guess that the integral diverges, but I wonder why Mathematica is not telling me this (gives me a finite result even). Furthermore, this integral corresponds to a physical observable which is of course expected to be finite. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: `NIntegrate` generally will not be able to deduce divergence. `Integrate` can more often do this.

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
Integrate[(1/(dyz^(5/2) Sqrt[\[Pi]])) (1/16 + 
I/16) E^(-((I (kR^2 + 2 kyz^2))/(2 kyz))) kyz^(-(3/2) + p + q) vt^
q (dyz (I + 8 dyz kyz) (Cos[dyz kyz] - I Sin[dyz kyz]) + (-I + 
8 dyz kyz) Abs[dyz] (-I Cos[dyz kyz] + Sin[dyz kyz])), {kyz, 1, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {p > 0, q > 0, p + q > 1, kR > 0, vt > 0, dyz > 0}]
```

> Integrate::idiv: Integral of (E^(-((I (kR^2+2 <<3>>^2))/(2 kyz))) kyz^(p+q) vt^q ((-1+8 dyz kyz) Cos[dyz kyz]+(1+8 dyz kyz) Sin[dyz kyz]))/(8 (dyz kyz)^(3/2) Sqrt[[Pi]]) does not converge on {1,[Infinity]}.

and

```
Integrate[BesselJ[0, dyz*kyz]*kyz/Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2]*
E^(-I*Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2])*(-kR*vt + Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2])^p*
(-kR + vt*Sqrt[kR^2 + kyz^2])^q, {kyz, 0, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> {p > 0, q > 0, p + q > 3/2, kR > 0, vt > 0, dyz > 0}]
```

> Integrate::idiv: Integral of (E^(-I Sqrt[kR^2+kyz^2]) kyz (Sqrt[kR^2+kyz^2]-kR vt)^p (-kR+Sqrt[kR^2+kyz^2] vt)^q BesselJ[0,dyz kyz])/Sqrt[kR^2+kyz^2] does not converge on {0,[Infinity]}.

show the divergence in the general case.